# Roofing for the porch

Tags: framing, roofing

I have front porch where three roof trusses with three cross slopes form the walls. How do I build the roof that covers the opening between walls, where each wall supports a roof sloping in different directions. [image]

Comment: How do you plan to support the front edge of the roof?

Comment: It would seem that your architect and builder chose "do not build a roof here." Adding one will make the rooms with the windows that look out here quite dark, for one thing. Probably a roof supported by posts and not connected to the house at all would be the most straightforward method.

Comment: Plus you'll have two valleys coming together at a point, which means that three drain planes all converge there. Rain storms would be a bit crazy.

Comment: Photos that show the actual roof, plus the building layout, would be much more useful.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. The question calls for a designer with details of the existing structure and a conversation with the owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being able to put a roof structure in this location would be fairly difficult due to the three sides facing this area and the water run off would collect in this area. Unless you wanted to plan on redoing the entire roof structure, I would look at alternative items to fill this space.

Depending on where you live and the weather you experience you have to plan accordingly. If you have a higher rainfall, then you need to make sure this structure won't impede the roof's water drainage. If you have snow pack, then you need something that is structurally strong. If you experience high winds, you need to make sure the structure is wind resistant.

Again, depending on your local weather, what I would suggest looking into would shade sails, or Fabric Porch coverings.

[image: Covered Porch]

These structures are simple to construct, and fairly in-expensive. I was looking at this [website](https://www.superiorawning.com/patio-covers-2/page/6/) for ideas, and I feel like this one is closest to the area that you are wanting to fill:

[image: Porch Covering Suggestion]